# cakephp flash messages dissapearing on apache server

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, nginx

Been stuck for a few hours here!

I am using cakephp 2.4.4 and I have pretty standard redirects with flash messages. For some reason the flash messages don't appear on my production server(running apache)?! If I comment out the redirect the flash message appears.

My app appears to work perfectly on my development server (which is running nginx).

Does anyone have any ideas?

```
$this->Session->setFlash(__('The User -'.$e["User"]['name'].'('.$e["User"]['resource_payroll_number'].') - Has been Activated'), 'alert', array('class' => 'alert-success'));

$this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
```

Comment: What you are describing is probably either: 1) having no session at all 2) The flash message being displayed on a 404 page (e.g. a 404 page for some missing css/js file that is requested but you're not looking at).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This must be because of the debug level you have. Check the core.php file.

```
/**
* CakePHP Debug Level:
*
* Production Mode:
* 0: No error messages, errors, or warnings shown. Flash messages redirect.
*
* Development Mode:
* 1: Errors and warnings shown, model caches refreshed, flash messages halted.
* 2: As in 1, but also with full debug messages and SQL output.
*
* In production mode, flash messages redirect after a time interval.
* In development mode, you need to click the flash message to continue.
*/
Configure::write('debug', 2);
```

This is copied [from github cakephp](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.8/app/Config/core.php#L21-L34)

Comment: debug level is set to 0? Is that not what it should be?

Comment: Debug level should *always* be 0 on a production site!

Comment: Yes debug should be set to 0 but i think this is causing that. Set debug to 0 also on development server and check if you see the flash messages.

Comment: If you saw my previous comments: Whoops sorry, that doc comments is pretty ambiguous. That's not actually referring to flash messages, it's [the archaic and barely used controller flash method](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.8/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php#L995-L1015) which [only automatically redirects in production mode](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.8/app/View/Layouts/flash.ctp#L24-L26) - that's not related to _session_ flash messages not working.

Comment: It seems to be related to Apache as I spun up a fresh server using Nginx and it works perfectly (regardless of what debug level is set). Would still like to know what the actual problem is though!

Comment: @AD7six I used to remember something like this that's why I posted this answer. Don't know if it would be best to delete this for not misguiding someone.

Comment: @MponosGeorge you could just add a disclaimer at the top of the answer - to a new reader/user it might _sound_ relevant, just as it did to you. Knowing what the problem isn't is also helpful.